# Would this ssh configuration allow host1 to access host3?

Tags: networking, ssh

I wanted to get a proxy on a friend's computer but our ISPs don't allow port forwarding. I had a remote Linux instance and thought maybe this idea could work:

[image: diagram]

host1 (me) would connect to host2 (Linux box) while forwarding p0 on host1 to p1 on host2. host3 (friend) would connect to host2 while forwarding p1 on host2 to p2 on host3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should work. I tried it at my Linux machines.

- The command `ssh -R p1:localhost:p2 user@host2` at host3 creates a listening socket p1 at host 2 that is tunneled to p2 at host3
- The command `ssh -L p0:localhost:p1 user@host2` at host1 creates a listening socket p0 at host1 that is tunneled to p1 at host2

So a http://localhost:p0 at host1 is tunneled to p1 at host2 and p1 at host2 is tunneled to p2 at host3

I tested this as follows:

- host3: start a web server
- host3: `ssh -R 10443:localhost:443 user@host2`
- host1: `ssh -L 443:localhost:10443 user@host2`
- host1: firefox -> https://localhost

Comment: This answer should contain more information on the reason it works. Specifically what configuration changes would be needed.